# Zipping Bazel-generated files for deployment

Tags: python, c++, build, bazel

I have a Bazel project that contains a `python/` folder in the root. This folder contains two files:

```
# BUILD
py_binary(
    name = "foo",
    srcs = ["foo.py"],
    deps = ["//cc:bar"],
)
```

and

```
# foo.py
import cc.bar as bar

# This is a SWIG-wrapped C++ function that prints "hello world"
print(bar.hello_world())
```

The `cc/` folder, which is also in the root, contains (among other things) the following rule:

```
# Expose the shared object library to Python.
py_library(
    name = "bar",
    srcs = [":bar_swig.py"], # Generated by SWIG.
    data = [":_bar.so"], # Generated by SWIG.
    visibility = ["//python:__pkg__"],
)
```

Running `bazel build //python:foo` generates `bazel-bin/python/foo.runfiles/` and `bazel-bin/python/foo`. I would like to write a rule in Bazel that gathers this directory and binary and zips them in `foo.zip`.

This is what I came up with:

```
genrule(
    name = "zip_foo",
    srcs = ["//python:foo"],
    outs = ["foo.zip"],
    cmd = "zip $@ $(locations //python:foo)",
)
```

However, the generated zip does not include `foo.runfiles/`. How do I write a rule that zips all of a target's runtime dependencies? I would like this rule to be as generic as possible, by which I mean it should handle zipping any target's runtime, even if the target has complex dependencies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `srcs` attribute of `genrule` will not build runfiles tree for binaries. Bazel will only build a runfiles tree if it expects something to run that binary on the host system as part of the build or test. Instead, we can use the `tools` attribute of `genrule`, which is intended for binaries that will run as part of the genrule. The following `genrule` will zip up the python binary and its runfiles tree.

```
genrule(
    name = "zip_foo",
    tools = ["//python:foo"],
    outs = ["foo.zip"],
    cmd = "zip -r $@ $(location //python:foo)*",
)
```

*DISCLAIMER:* This will build `//python:foo` in the "host configuration". What this means is that any native code will be built for the architecture of the machine that you are running bazel on. So if you build `foo.zip` on Linux and copy it onto a Mac, it will probably not work.

Comment: That is fine, I use this in a CI pipeline that uses the same architecture as the deployment environment. Thank you.